# URL method for an api call

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am creating an API in which I am getting the data witj either Number or Name.

```
 var method = require("../../app/models/model_METHOD.js");
    module.exports = (function(){
        'user strict';
    var router=require('express').Router();
        router.get('/search',function (req,res) {   

           var name = req.query.name;
           var  number = req.query.number;
           var query       = {};  
            if(name){
                 var pattern = new RegExp(name,"i");
                 query = {Name: {$regex: pattern}},{Name:1,_id:0};
                method.find(query).lean()
                .limit(20)
                .exec(function(err,results){
                    results=results.map(function(doc){return doc.Name});
                            if(err){
                                console.log("DB error");
                                console.log(err);
                                res.status(500).send("Error");
                            }
                            else if(results.length!=0){ 
                            console.log(results.length);


                                res.status(200).send(results);
                            }
                            else{
                                res.status(404).send('no matching records found');
                            }
                });
            }
            else if(number){

                var pattern = new RegExp(number,"i");
                console.log(pattern);
                 query = {Number: {$regex: pattern}},{Number:1,_id:0,Code:0,Name:0,collection:0};
                method.find(query).lean()
                .limit(20)
                .exec(function(err,results){
                    results = results.map(function(item){return item.Number});
                            if(err){
                                console.log("DB error");
                                console.log(err);
                                res.status(500).send("Error");
                            }
                            else if(results.length!=0){ 
                               console.log(results.length);
                                res.status(200).send(results);
                            }
                            else{
                                res.status(404).send('no matching records found');
                            }
                });

            }
            else{
                    res.status(400).send('input can not be empty');
                }

        });
```

I am setting the URL for calling these api's as following:-

```
function getName(key) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/method/search?name=' + key.key
            });
        }

        function getNumber(key) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'api/method/search?number=' + key.key
            });
        }
```

Although the above methods are working for me but instead of creating two different functions can I call this in one URL, if its name then `name=' + key.key` else if number then `number=' + key.key`.
Something like this:- `'api/method/search?name=' + key.key or number=' + key.key`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, call the same method and pass a string with the type:

```
function get(key, type) {// type will have to be either "name" or "number"
  return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/method/search?' + type + '=' + key.key
  });
}
```